# Is Atomic Samurai speed in the same level of Flashy Flash?

Tags: one-punch-man

I found this comment in a forum

> Should'nt Atomic Samurai be sub relativistic since the databook puts
>   his speed on the same level as Flashy flash?

Is this true? Is Atomic Samurai speed in the same level of Flashy Flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give at best a partial answer.  The part I can give are the databook pages concerning Atomic Samurai and Flashy Flash:
[image: Atomic samurai databook, in Japanese]
[image: Flashy Flash databook, in Japanese]

Their statblocks are nearly identical, and the one stat they have a max rating in is the same.  [According to a post in a gamefaqs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/2000121-anime-and-manga-other-titles/72639438) the stats listed in order are

1. (Tairyoku)Physical strength/Stamina
2. (Chiryoku)Intelligence
3. (Seigi-kan)Sense of Justice
4. (Jikyu-ryoku)Endurance
5. **(Shunpatsu Ryoku)Instantaneous Force/Speed**
6. (Ninki)Popularity
7. (Jiiseki)Success/actual Results
8. (hero-specific ability rating)

I've bolded the one stat they both have at maximum.

However, these are not objective stat blocks, they are stat blocks from the perspective of the Heroes Association (or possibly Genos, as there's a Saitama stat block later that's specifically from Genos's perspective).  King, for example, has max stats in every single category, which we know to not be objectively accurate.

Comment: is this the same hero rating shown in the One Punch Man wikia? There they claim item 5 is "power" , when all the others have the same name.

Comment: @Pablo The wikia should be using the databook entries, yes. I think it's hard to pin down the translations due to Japanese being what it is relative to English.  "Instantaneous force" would sound rather like power.  In the real world an incredibly fast attack is pretty much the same thing as an incredibly strong attack, since that's how kinetic energy works. Though in most super hero settings they're often considered separate things, where people can attack at ultra-relativistic speeds and still somehow hit like a feather and not blow up the atmosphere.